# Progress dialog not showing and skip to show result

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a fake loading for progress dialog. Here is my code:

```
final ProgressFragment progressDialog = new ProgressFragment();
    progressDialog.setProgressMessage("Generating summary. Please wait.");
    progressDialog.show(fragment.getFragmentManager(), null);

    PdfView.createWebPrintJob(fragment.getActivity(), webViewResult, directory, fileName, new PdfView.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void success(String path) {
            fragment.dismiss();
            progressDialog.showOk("Success.", "");
        }

        @Override
        public void failure() {
            fragment.dismiss();
            progressDialog.showOk("Failed.", "");
        }
    });
```

I wanted to show the "Generating summary. Please wait." for about 3 seconds before showing the result. However, the code above show the result immediately without showing the "Generating summary. Please wait." message. Any ideas how to make a fake wait? Thanks!

Comment: Use multithreading, `sleep` for 3 seconds and then show the result in that thread. Best thing to use here is `AsyncTask`

Comment: Use Handler postDelayed method https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20java.lang.Object,%20long)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution which is by using Handler. It does not block the main thread, so UI stays responsive.

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }, 1000 * 50);
```